# Run disk error check on NTFS file?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem-corruption, file-corruption

I have a feeling that my system hard drive is dying. Benchmark kind of enforces it. Here is the benchmark of my system hard drive during low system activity:

[image: System hard drive benchmark]

And here is the benchmark of backup drive:

[image: Backup hard drive benchmark]

Furthermore, there are some files which I just can't touch because I get CRC errors and the hard drive activity spikes to 100% with operating speeds less than 1 MB/s while working with such files.

I haven't yet tried swapping SATA cable as I have read this might cause the problems. Anyway, I would like to run some tests on specific clustsers where those files I am interested in are stored.

I don't want to do the full chkdsk because it takes a very long time.

I would like to either find the utility which executes the disk check directly on the clusters where the file belongs or a couple utilities where one tells me the cluster locations and another can check just those locations.

How do I check and possibly fix disk errors where the files I am interested in are stored?

Edit: S.M.A.R.T. info:

[image: S.M.A.R.T.]

Comment: `chkdsk` already does what you want, by the way. It’s slow if the drive is slow (because it’s failing or whatever). With 65 pending sectors, it’s time to look for a new disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) and run it, and post the S.M.A.R.T. info in your question.

What you want to look at in particular are the reallocated sector count and the pending sector reallocations.

When you say you get CRC errors, what application is telling you this?

Neither the harddrive nor the filesystem (NTFS) tracks the CRCs of files.

You can't fix disk errors. Disk errors are bad sectors on the disk. The drive will automatically remap them, but at some point you just have to copy all the data off and put it onto a new drive.

Comment: Added S.M.A.R.T. info in the original post. I get CRC errors when syncing the files with FreeFileSync. It uses CopyFileEx WinAPI function. But I can't even open those files.
I have all of my important data backed up, except for some minor updates. However, if I can't fix the drive, I would like to know if I should change it since it is still covered by warranty.

Comment: @paulius_l It looks like that drive is beginning to fail. It's not had to reallocate sectors yet (which happens when it *knows* a sector is bad), but you've got a number of pending sectors. These don't necessarily mean it's bad - these do happen from time to time - but pending means that the disk had trouble reading those sectors, and the next time that the system tries to read those sectors, it'll mark them bad if it can't read them a second time, or clear them if it can successfully read them.

Comment: @paulius_l I would grab a linux LiveCD and use that to read the contents of the entire disk once to force a re-check on those pending sectors. You can do that with `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1M` (where `/dev/sda` is the disk; it might be `/dev/sdb` if you have multiple disks attached. In any case, the command is a non-destructive read operation, so it shouldn't cause harm if you pick the wrong disk). You can end it early with Ctrl+C.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I have actually had problems with Windows on this drive before. Used Linux to backup the data and reformat it and installed Windows again. It worked fine for a week until now when I started getting this weird behavior again. I think it is strange that those operations didn't uncover anything in S.M.A.R.T. as I have been checking it previously and results have always been good. This is actually the first time I am seeing any errors here.

Comment: @paulius_l S.M.A.R.T. is not perfect, sadly. It is more about diagnostic information than an exhaustive check for all possible ways a drive can fail. If S.M.A.R.T. says your drive is failing, then it's *probably* failing (but might be fine), and it's just as probable that the drive might fail without anything noteworthy showing up in logs until everything is suddenly gone.

Comment: I have been running chkdsk on the drive for the past few hours and it is very slow. The "Current Pending Sector Count" now is 242 and it is rising, so the problem looks more serious than it did initially. Apparently, in order for the pending sectors to be reallocated it is not enough to read to them - they must be written to, as I have read on some forums.

Comment: @paulius_l That sounds about right. Also, at 242 pending sectors and rising, that disk should be replaced asap.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Read errors and reallocated sectors are symptoms of dying disk.

You have very high read error rate, it has a lot of reallocated sector count etc.

Maybe thats just some sectors, maybe it is partial damage and disk firmware can deal with that by reallocating sectors, but **that disk is not reliable anymore**.

Backup your all important data and replace disk ASAP if you can.